# Autowire MongoRepository in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I want to Autowire MongoRepository into my service class, and I'm not able to do this. I'm using java config.
This is my repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    public User findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<User> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

This is the Service which uses UserRepository:

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    public void save(User user) {
        repository.save(user);
    }
}
```

This is part of my Controller which uses service:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService service;
```

My main java config class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableMongoRepositories
@Import({MjurAppConfig.class, MongoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan({"prv.makro.mjur.controller"})
public class MjurWebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

MjurAppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"prv.makro.mjur.dao", "prv.makro.mjur.repository"})
public class MjurAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public User getUser() {
        return new User();
    }

    @Bean
    public TestService getTestService() {
        return new TestService();
    }
}
```

And mongo config:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoFactoryBean mongo() {
        MongoFactoryBean mongo = new MongoFactoryBean();
        mongo.setHost("localhost");
        mongo.setPort(27017);
        return mongo;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception{
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo().getObject(),"mjur");
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private prv.makro.mjur.repository.UserRepository 
prv.makro.mjur.service.impl.FirstService.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [prv.makro.mjur.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I was searching for resolution for this problem but I couldn't find anything.
IMO Component scan should find the repository and it should bind it to spring context. Sadly it's not working like that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, the problem was with `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotation.

When I have added package name to it's body (so it looked like:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories({"prv.makro.mjur.repository"}) )
```

I was able to autowire my UserRepository

Comment: Same problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your repository interface with `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation.

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID> {

}
```

2. Create your Repository implementation

```java
public class MyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends SimpleMongoRepository<T, ID> {

    public PermissableRepositoryImpl(
        final MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata,
        final MongoOperations mongoOperations
    ) {

        super(metadata, mongoOperations);
    }
}
```

3. Add `@EnableMongoRepository` annotation to your appropriate Configuration or Application class.

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder) {

        return applicationBuilder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (after comments and alter of the posted code)

This is happening because the Spring Web application has 2 contexts: 1 is the root context and another one is the Web context (the one you register by the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation).

Please do the following:

1) Remove the `@Import` annotation from your `MjurWebAppConfig` - remember this is your web context.
2) Add the `@Import` in the `MjurAppConfig` config essentially looking like:

```
@Configuration
@Import({MongoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan({"prv.makro.mjur.dao", "prv.makro.mjur.repository"})
public class MjurAppConfig {
//..
```

These steps should make visible your autowired DAO bean inside your Service bean.

---

Before EDIT:

I bet your `TestService` bean is under package `prv.makro.mjur.service` judging by the component scan annotation:

```
@ComponentScan({"prv.makro.mjur.controller"})
```

In other words `@ComponentScan` cannot see your TestService to register the `@Autowired` dependency.

Make sure `TestService` is visible by your component scan and under the above assumption if you do:

```
@ComponentScan({"prv.makro.mjur"})
```

it should work.

Comment: You're right, but in MjurAppConfig I have defined Test service using @Bean annotation. Anyway - I added that package to componentScan annotation and it throws the same error

Comment: I think that error may be caused because UserRepository is an interface, and Repository annotation should be on implementation class. However if I will create class which will implement this interface, I will have to write implementation of all methods like save or findBy

Comment: look at my answer - i've added initial section after your updates

Comment: Thanks for your time dimitrisli, I tried the way you described (before and after edit) but It didn't helped. I solved issue by adding repository package to @EnableMongoRepositories . Please note that I didn't had problem with autowiring DAO, I had a problem with autowiring MongoRepository class.